# How to use video mask in moviepy?

Tags: python, moviepy

I have a video of a white square moving around a black background, and I want to use it as a mask for a video to be layered on another video. I've tried this code and it doesn't work, and I've tried to use a non-moving PNG instead and it still doesn't work. How do you actually use the masking in moviepy? If it has to do with something about the RGB dimensions, didn't the documentation said it would be automatically converted to greyscale?

```
from moviepy.editor import *

main_clip = VideoFileClip("mastertest.mp4").subclip(0,6)
mask_clip = VideoFileClip("maintest.mp4").subclip(0,6)
mask1 = VideoFileClip("mask_testing.mp4")
mask1 = mask1.to_mask()

mask_clip.set_mask(mask1)

final_clip = CompositeVideoClip([main_clip, mask_clip.resize(0.5)])
final_clip.write_videofile("resultmask.mp4")
```